# Is there a more efficient way other than brute force for Project Euler #5?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, math

I'm going through project euler, and like a lot of people, I get stuck on efficiency. I don't mind something like trying to reduce the time from 7ms to 6ms, but I do care about having to wait half an hour for my loops.
The question is:

> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

I think I have a valid solution in python, but it's terribly inefficient.

```
import sys
import math

def multiple():
    multiple = 20
    multiples = []
    while multiple < math.sqrt(sys.maxsize):
        div_flag = False
        max_flag = False
        for i in range(2, 21):
            if multiple % i == 0:
                div_flag = True
                if i == 20:
                    max_flag = True
                else:
                    max_flag = False
            if multiple % i != 0:
                div_flag = False
                break
        if max_flag == True:
            multiples.append(multiple)
            multiple = math.sqrt(sys.maxsize)
        multiple += 20
        print(multiple, "div_flag: " + str(div_flag), "max_flag: " + str(max_flag), str(multiples)) 
    # These prints are just there for debugging.
    print(multiples)



multiple()
```

As you can see, it loops through every number until the sqrt() of the max safe integer. The reason for the `sqrt()` was because I tried to make it more efficient, but it never got to that point anyway. I left it running for about 15 minutes, and it was up to something like 2 million (This was when the variable `multiples` was at 2 and incremented by 1). Then, I tried to increase the `multiple` variable by 20 (shown above) and in a little more than 15 minutes, I had 45 million. I looked at the answer when I was doing project euler, and that was somewhere around 200 million. I wasn't cheating, I was just making sure that there was a problem with my program and it wasn't skipping that goal number. What would make it so I could get an answer in, under a minute, I say. As I said, I'm not an efficiency freak, I just want to see a result in under a minute.

I'm fairly new to python, so I know there are some pretty obvious answers.

P.S. **I wouldn't like a direct rewrite of my code, so maybe bits of example code here and there, and a few hints would be good.** (So I actually learn and improve my coding.)

Comment: In practice, you only have to perform a prime decomposition of each number, and just keep the maximum exponent of each prime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with project Euler, but this problem isn't really a programming problem, but a math problem.  The answer is just 2^4 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19.

If you try looking at every number starting from 1 until you find one that fits the criterion, you're solving the problem wrong.

Your goal is to calculate `lcm(1, 2, 3, 4, .... 20)`, the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).  Some search on stackoverflow will show you how to calculate the lcm of a list of numbers.  Amusingly enough, `math.lcm` will be added to Python 3.9.

Comment: 2^4 is the largest power of 2 that is ≤ 20.  3^2 is the largest power of 3.  Likewise, 5^1, 7^1, ... for every prime up to 20.    

For the more general problem, lcm(a, b, c, d, . . .) is defined to be the smallest number that is divisible by a, b, c, d, ..., exactly what you're looking for.  StackOverflow has ample information on how to calculate this in Python.